# Glassfish: Deploying application in domain failed; Error loading deployment descriptors - invalid bit length repeat

Tags: deployment, glassfish, deployment-descriptor

I'm trying to deploy a .war trough the server's web interface. Getting the same error when deploying it as an exploded directory with IDEA.
What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The message points to an exception in java.util.zip thus implicating a corrupted packed file. Maybe you could try rebuilding the war file.